# How to term query nested json objects/fields in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am doing term aggregation based on field [type] like below but elastic is returning only 1 term count instead of 2 it is not doing nested object aggregation i.e under comments.data.comments[is a list] under this i have 2 type.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "genres": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "comments.data.comments.type"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your mapping ?

Comment: i am not sure about the mapping as i am new to elastic search.

Comment: I used your mapping which you commented earlier and can you provide your proper search query, one which you gave have issues

Comment: {
    "aggs": {
        "genres": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "events.ecommerceData.comments.recommendationType"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: it is already present in the question

Comment: yes it works for me.. gives count as abc 1

Comment: i enabled field data

Comment: works for you now?

Comment: Sorry! document was incorrect i corrected it.. you can try now....it is in the question section.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211370/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-tirumalesh).

Comment: luckily it started to working thanks guys.. and after that i added a filter in the same search query but now elastic is not fetching the records..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gotta utilize the `nested` field type:

```
PUT events
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "events": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "ecommerceData": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "comments": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "recommendationType": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST events/_doc
{
  "events": [
    {
      "eventId": "1",
      "ecommerceData": [
        {
          "comments": [
            {
              "rank": 1,
              "recommendationType": "abc"
            },
            {
              "rank": 1,
              "recommendationType": "abc"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

GET events/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "events.ecommerceData.comments"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "nested_comments_recomms": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "events.ecommerceData.comments.recommendationType"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi jzzfs..Thanks for the right solution.. and the mapping you shown is not working for existing index... and i have re posted my original document..

Comment: Gotta drop the index & resync.

Comment: Also, looks like you changed `ecommerceData ` to `recommendationData` so make sure you change it in the mapping too.

Comment: i did that it is throwing error object mapping [events] can't be changed from non-nested to nested

Comment: Nope -- dropping the index means deleting it. `curl -XDELETE ...`

Comment: can't i add mapping on existing index

Comment: not if you have breaking changes -- and [nested] is one of those.

Comment: ok.. how can i do mapping from java rest high level client any idea.

Comment: There's plenty of resources... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552845/configure-elasticsearch-mapping-with-java-api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211445/discussion-between-jzzfs-and-tirumalesh).